# Cannot access tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm getting this error in Android Studio:

> "Cannot access class 'org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies"

What is the problem ? and How can I fix it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the following item in the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0-rc1'
}
```

Comment: You should also explain why that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this worked for me instead:

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:+'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:+'
```

Comment: You should also explain why that should work